# How to use/hold a weapon in Gothic 1?

Tags: gothic

I have obtained a weapon in Gothic 1: a pickaxe. However there doesn't seem to be a way to hold it? How do I hold the pickaxe as my weapon?

Gothic 1 is all keyboard-friendly and have run through options but don't get the option to hold weapons. I can see it in the inventory though.

Comment: @Timelord64 - It's known as [Gothic 1 on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65540/)

Comment: @Timelord64 - No argument here, just pointing out why I made the tag so :)

Comment: haha. I just realised OP hadn't originally made the tag.. I still think the two should be linked, I think you might have more power to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> should equip weapons unless you've changed the controls in the options.